# Facing problem at codeigniter multiple word search

Tags: php, codeigniter, full-text-search

I am creating a CodeIgniter search for my bookshop project. It is okay with a single word search but I am facing the problem when I search with multiple words. How I can fix this problem.

**MY controller**

```
public function search()
{
    /*=== LOAD DYNAMIC CATAGORY ===*/
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
    $view['category'] = $this->admin_model->get_category();
    /*==============================*/


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('search_book', "Search",'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        #...Redirected same page after action
        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
    else
    {
        $query = $this->input->post('search_book');

        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $view['books'] = $this->user_model->search($query);


        $view['user_view'] = "users/search_books";
        $this->load->view('layouts/user_layout', $view);
    }

}
```

**MY Model**

```
public function search($query)
{
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->from('books');
    $this->db->like('book_name', $query);
    $this->db->where('status', 1);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    return $q->result();
}
```

Like if I write **PHP** in my search box it brings my all books which title have the word PHP. It is okay for me.

but when I write **PHP BOOKS** in my search box it shows me no book found.

I want it to show the result if any word is matched.

Comment: Against which string you are searching `PHP BOOKS`, can we get sample string?

Comment: your `like` clause query in the search might need to look like this `$this->db-like('book_name', '%'.$query.'%'`

Comment: @RahulMeshram against $query string.

Comment: sample string I means, `PHP PHP PHP` or `BOOKS BOOKS BOOKS` or `PHP BOOKS PHP`, are you getting me?

Comment: When you enter a multi-word search, would you expect to return results that include both words, results with either word, or results including both words in order with the space between?

Comment: @RahulMeshram okay I got your point. there is no book name like php books. what I want that is if I write php book it brings me these books which having the name php. sample string **PHP And Mysql**. this is a book name in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace this

```
$this->db->like('book_name', $query);
```

with condition  as

```
$str = str_replace(" ","|", $query);
$this->db->where("book_name rlike '$str'");
```

You can get more details about rlike [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp).

Here is a better [full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) help provided for your reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot, brother! It fixes my problem. @RahulMeshram